# Onload animate and delay

Tags: javascript

I have 3 divs and I want after the page loads delay 0.5  then scroll to second div delay 0.5 then scroll to 3rd div. but my problem is I cannot get it to auto scroll to any of the divs

```
<div id="mydiv">Content</div>
<div id="mydiv2">Content2</div>
<div id="mydiv3">Content3</div>


$(window).on('load', function () {  
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv2").offset().top
    }, 2000);

 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv3").offset().top
    }, 3000);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just have a typo. You had $("#myDiv2") vs $("#mydiv2"). Also use $(document).ready() instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mydiv2").offset().top
    }, 2000);

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mydiv3").offset().top
    }, 3000);

});
```

[jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/4629b2r3/)

Comment: thanks @Nick Cordova is there any way to delay like 0.5 sec?

Comment: Yes, $('html, body').delay(500).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mydiv3").offset().top
    }, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

You onload event isn't valid try this universal onload from Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {  ... add you code here ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your HTML.  Your divs are mydiv with a lower case 'D', but you are referencing #myDiv with an uppercase 'D'.

Comment: But you also need to use $(document).ready(), and try adding .delay(500) at the end of your animate functions like this:
 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv3").offset().top
    }, 3000).delay(500);

});